# UITextField text in UITableViewCell auto reset when scroll down and turn back?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

i have a uitableview with muliplte cell. which contains textfileds ,sow when i enter text on textfield and scroll the tableview entered text is erasing
My code is

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        ComplaintsCustomCell *cell=(ComplaintsCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];        
        if(cell==nil){
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ComplaintsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

            for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){

                if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                    cell = (ComplaintsCustomCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSDictionary *dict=[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.complaintID_label.text=[dict valueForKey:@"ProblemName"];

        if(cell.notesView!=nil)
        cell.notesView.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Notes"];
           [cell.notesView setTag:indexPath.row +6000];

        cell.durationFld.text=[dict valueForKey:@"Duration"];
        [cell.durationFld setTag:indexPath.row + 5000];
        cell.durationFld.delegate=self;
```

Comment: Where are your UITextFieldDelegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

Your class also needs to be the delegate of each of the text fields, detect each text change and update the associated model object (your array of dictionaries).